# Is it okay to target * with jQuery and css?

Tags: jquery, css

I was working on a concept when the user hovers over a certain element I want everything on the DOM to make the change. Then I want to append a new element in after for the user to use.

This all works great if I target `*.active` in css and then target `$('*');` with jQuery but I feel that may not be a good approach.

It seems to be valid css,

> W3C CSS Validator results for TextArea (CSS level 3)
>
> Congratulations! No Error Found. This document validates as CSS level
>   3 !

Is this safe to do or is this a bad practice?

Is there any downsides to doing this?

Here is a fiddle I made for this question, [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wADz4/).

Comment: If it's your only option, then you don't really have much of a choice do you. If you need to select all elements in the dom, `$('*')` is the only practical way.

Comment: @KevinB It is not the only option I can target each html tag and do it that way but I figured, if valid to do so, it would be much simpler to do it with `*`.

Comment: Right, but selecting each html tag isn't practical with the number of possible html tags out there, unless theres only a small subset of them that you want to target.

Comment: As far as I know there are performance issues with the `*` selector, but if that is all that works, you may be stuck...

Comment: Add a class to `body` like `.everythingActive` and use `body.everythingActive *` in your CSS.  Much faster as `$('*')` loops over every single element anywhere.  Do it like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/wADz4/3/).

Comment: From your fiddle it looks like this may cause problems, as whenever you mouse over anything, every element on the page gets the active class, probably not your intention.

Comment: You could try creating a test case with [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/), but I can't image selecting with `*` would be slower than selecting each tag separately, assuming applying something to every tag on the page was your goal.

Comment: @DrCord I just through an example together to see if it would work. What my idea is once the user activates this click event I want the entire page to fold inward like a closing book. Then I will append in the related content to the user, once they are finished the page then opens back in and fades out the append element. I am just concerned about performance, valid code, and how to close a lot of elements that will be on the page.

Comment: @MattBurland I will give that a try and see how it works out, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The universal selector is perfectly valid.

The reason it's feared (somewhat rightfully so) is because it's the most expensive selector - but [apparently it still ain't that bad](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-09-28/css_tip_star_selector_not_that_bad.aspx). I can't imagine jQuery will take that much of a performance hit either.

I think it's probably better than giving every element a class of "select-all-these-elements", anyway.

Comment: jQuery *isn't* CSS. For instance, `$("*")` will *fetch every element* from the DOM. Browser CSS engines are smart, and while there are some degenerate cases, handle the universal selector (or any other wildly general selector) well, as this is what they are designed to do.

Comment: You're not wrong. But still, in most real-world scenarios, using `$('*')` sparingly will have a negligible performance hit. Try it yourself. And in this case since there's no real alternative than to select all elements anyway, this is probably the best selector to use.

Answer (score 2):

This is, as far as I know, perfectly legal, but do you really need to select every tag? If it's just a css adjustment, you could add a rule like this:

```
.active * {background-color: #ff0000;}
```

and add the `active` class to the `body` element.

Answer (score 2):

It's safe until the DOM starts to get large, when things are bound to get less than rosy. That's the downside.

You should seriously consider the alternative of adding a class to `body` and using CSS such as

```
body.active * { ... }
```

Comment: Hmm okay, so if I make this animation of the current page close and appending the new content in. Then would I not have the problem with my body being closed? I am starting to see the problem with `*` I just don't know the best approach to go about this.

Comment: @JoshPowell: I cannot answer that because "this animation of the current page close" is about three paragraphs under-specified. If you gave a concrete example to discuss...

Comment: I could later on but this was the start of my idea. :/ I can already see, after all of these great answers, that the `*` will not work and was doing far more then I originally hoped. Once I get a solid start on the project I will fill you in, I just couldn't find much on using `*` in a script. I think what I will do is add everything into a main parent for the elements I need to hide, once the event is fired I don't have to worry about everything getting those styles.

Answer (score 0):

Using `*` in CSS is valid, but you should try to avoid to use it because it has a performance penalty. This is because browsers evaluate CSS from right to left. So for example, take this selector:

```
div * {
  ... some css ...
}
```

The browser will first create a list of ALL elements and then only return the ones that have a div as one of its parents. This can take up a lot of memory and have a negative impact on rendering speed.

So * works, but don't use it too much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok is relative to the complexity of your Javascript application. It also depends if you're targeting newer browsers or older ones as jQuery works less efficiently within older browsers.

I would avoid using $('*') for any serious/complex applications.

Have a read through this article which provides some basic recommendations.
http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/